# How to set forward voltage for a diode model in NGSpice?

Tags: ngspice

I am trying to understand the documentation for the diode model, but I could not find how to set the forward voltage value.

Can someone help me simulate silicon diode that has a forward voltage of approximately 0.7 volts?

Comment: What documentation? What diode model? What software?

Comment: docs at http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs.html , NGSpice software, the diode model is what I am asking about, I need a model for forward voltage of approximately 0.7 volts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not simply "set" the forward voltage. The forward voltage is determined by a combination of model parameters. Here's a model I found for the 1N4148 which is a commonly used Silicon diode:

```
******************************************
*1N4148
*VRRM = 100V
*IFRM = 450 mA 
*trr  = 4ns
*
*Package: SOD 27
*
*Package Pin 1 : Cathode
*Package Pin 2 : Anode
*
*Simulator: PSPICE
*
******************************************
*
.SUBCKT 1N4148 1 2 
*
* The resistor R1 does not reflect 
* a physical device. Instead it
* improves modeling in the reverse 
* mode of operation.
*
R1 1 2 5.827E+9 
D1 1 2 1N4148
*
.MODEL 1N4148 D 
+ IS = 4.352E-9 
+ N = 1.906 
+ BV = 110 
+ IBV = 0.0001 
+ RS = 0.6458 
+ CJO = 7.048E-13 
+ VJ = 0.869 
+ M = 0.03 
+ FC = 0.5 
+ TT = 3.48E-9 
.ENDS
```

If you use these parameters with the standard PSPICE diode model you should get (I did not check it for you, so no guarantees) a diode with a forward voltage of around 0.7 V at "normal" forward operation (a couple of mA of current flowing).

Comment: Thank you! but how can I set these parameters for any forward voltage value I want? what would be the formula to get parameters values then?

Comment: Google "the diode equation".  It's at the core of the model used in SPICE (NGSpice or AnyOldSpice -- but not Old Spice; that's different).

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 7 of the NGSpice Manual defines all the diode parameters , but these are often not found in datasheets.

As a general rule Vf for a diode is given at a low current where the bulk resistance begins to  dominate the forward voltage which implies a linear V/I response above this current level and you know it has a logarithmic response at low currents.

[Si diode log curve](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/396369/17574)

I have discovered that the bulk resistance is related to the size and power rating of the diode such that Rs=0.5~1/Pmax which is good for estimating within 50%.  The best diodes are towards 0.25/Pmax=Rs and this also applies to LED’s, Zener’s and BJT’s to reasonably good correlation. The poorer diodes or older technology would be Rs>1/Pmax.  The Pmax is the 85’C steady max power rating, not the actual power dissipated.

### Concluding Remarks

0.6V @ 1mA @ 30’C applies to most Si diodes since it is low power and little or no self heating.

For all Si diodes, 0.7V may be at >> 1mA and not a good reference for small signal , low-current diodes rated for high speed.

This has a much wider current tolerance as Rs (Bulk resistance) , power dissipation , NTC (Vf  vs T) and other diode factors come to play near and above 0.7V. 
Thus the datasheets for all packages of **1N4148** depend on stated assumptions of Cu area heatsink, ambient T ...

> but have Vf (MAX) @ If specs ranging from ...

- 1.25V @ 150mA
- 1.2V @ 100mA
- 1V @ 100mA
- 1V @ 50mA
- 1V@ 10mA
- 0.855V @ 10mA

[Datasheets](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/diodes-rectifiers-single/280?FV=ffe00118&quantity=0&ColumnSort=-2261&page=1&stock=1&k=diodes%20rectifiers&k=4148&pageSize=500&pkeyword=diodes%20rectifiers)